# 2D array initialization in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

In Java, I have something like this

```
String arr[][] = new String[][];
for(int i=0;i<=count;i++) //"count" is some dynamically determined counter
{
    for(int j=0;j<=count;j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = //some assignment
    }
}
//retrival of the strings in the same manner
```

I want to declare an empty 2D array and then dynamically assign 'String' values to it and also retrieve them later.
How can I achieve this in Objective-C?

I checked out some answers on this topic but storing and retrival mechanism is still not clear to me.

Comment: The above will just initialize the diagonal.  You need a loop within a loop.

Comment: And this is basic C.  You should have a good basic understanding of C before you tackle Objective-C or you will have lots of problems.

Comment: I have edited the question @HotLicks
Sorry for my silly mistake.

Comment: Are you using C arrays or NSArrays?  Two (almost) totally different things.

Comment: I am using NSMutableArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you do the same with objects, but have to create instances for every inner array:

```
NSMutableArray *outer = [NSMutableArray new];
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i<=…; i++ )
{
  NSMutableArray *inner = [NSMutableArray new];
  for( NSUInteger j = 0; j<=…; j++ )
  {
     inner[j] = …;
  }
  outer[i] = inner;
}
```

Access:

```
id value = outer[…][…];
```

Maybe this is easier to understand, because double subscripting is used to write to the array while initializing it. But it has a performance penalty for the indexed access on the outer array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
for( NSUInteger i = 0; i<=…; i++ )
{
  array[i] = [NSMutableArray new];
  for( NSUInteger j = 0; j<=…; j++ )
  {
     array[i][j] = …;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain 'outer[i] = inner'
Does it mean that outer[i] will contain a reference to the entire inner array?

Comment: Yes, outer only contains references to arrays. If you want to have a stronger encapsulation, you can assign a copy.

Comment: I did an edit that probably makes it easier to understand.